# Flask Admin editing columns send requests

Tags: python, database, flask-admin

I am using flask-admin with ModelViews

```
class MyModel(ModelView):
    can_create = False
    can_edit = True
    column_list = ['column']
```

This allows me to edit the data on each row. However I want to perform some custom function in addition to the editing. I tried to add a route for the edit but it overrides the existing functionality.

```
@app.route('/admin/mymodelview/edit/', methods=['POST'])
def do_something_in_addition():
    ...
```

Is there any way to extend the existing edit functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override either the [after_model_change](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.after_model_change) method or the [on_model_change](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.on_model_change) methods in your view class.

For example :

```
class MyModel(ModelView):
    can_create = False
    can_edit = True
    column_list = ['column']

    def after_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        # model has already been commited here
        # do custom work
        pass

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created)
        # model has not been commited yet so can be changed
        # do custom work that can affect the model
        pass
```